# Uso do State e setState React Native

Tags: react, react-native

Estou tentando criar as variáveis que receberão os dados de Usuario e Senha,tentei de varias maneiras usando o state e setState, mas pelo modo como construí a minha aplicação não estou conseguindo. Obrigado pela ajuda

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../Style/LoginStyles'

// Tela de Login


const Login = ({ navigation }) => (


  <View style={styles.backgroundImage}>
    <View style={styles.WindowLogin}>
      <Text style={styles.Label}>Informe seus dados</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder='Login' style={styles.TextInput}/>
      <TextInput placeholder='Senha' style={styles.TextInput} secureTextEntry />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cadastro')}>
        <View style={styles.Button}>
          <Text style={{ color: '#FFF' } , {fontSize: 24}}>Entrar</Text>
        </View>           
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{ color: '#FFF' } , {fontSize: 18}}>Esqueci minha senha</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>    
    </View >        
  </View >

)

Login.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Home'
}

export default Login
```

Comment: Algum erro? Não tem nenhum state nesse seu código

Answer (score 1):

Explicação: Você está utilizando um stateless component, esse tipo de componente não tem estado, ou seja, state ou setState não vai funcionar. Você consegue apenas utilizar props. Por exemplo, ({ navigation }), que você utilizou, é uma propriedade. this.props.navigation, como você está usando usando desestruturação de ES6, funciona apenas com navigation.

Sugestões: Troca o stateless component por uma Component class

```
export default class NomeClass extends Component {

   constructor(props){
      super(props)

      this.state={
        name:"Guilherme Morgado",
        email:"morgado@yourdev.com.br",
      }      

 }}
```

Ou cria um component pai, em uma Component Class e chama seu stateless component, passando os valores via props.

Mais infos: https://itnext.io/react-component-class-vs-stateless-component-e3797c7d23ab

https://medium.com/groww-engineering/stateless-component-vs-pure-component-d2af88a1200b